# How do I find a mixed case entry in .gitmodules using `--get-regexp`?

Tags: git, git-config

I have a submodule defined in `.gitmodules` as

```
[submodule "FastFold"]
  path = .vim/pack/test/start/FastFold
  url = https://github.cim/Konfekt/FastFold.git
  ignore = dirty
```

I'm trying to get the path using `git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp "FastFold.path"` but that command returns nothing with an exit code of `1` (no match).

Docs for [`--get-regexp`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.15.4#Documentation/git-config.txt---get-regexp) state

> Regular expression matching is currently case-sensitive and done against a canonicalized version of the key in which section and variable names are lowercased, but subsection names are not.

I'm able to get the path for entries that are all lower-cased, so I'm pretty sure this is a valid regexp.

I wondered if the part of the quote above that said `variable names are lowercased` might mean `"fastfold.path"` would work, but that returns the same result.

How can I find the path for a mixed case submodule entry like this one? And how should I properly name the submodule to avoid this problem in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want either:

```
git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp '^submodule\.FastFold\.path$'
```

(in which case, `--get-regexp` is kind of pointless) or:

```
git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp "\.FastFold\.path"
```

(which doesn't seem right: don't you only want matching *submodule* entries?).  The `\.` makes the match require a literal dot, and the literal dot is needed to make `FastFold` a subsection name, so that it will not be canonicalized into lowercase.  Remember that `.` in a regular expression means "any character", not "a literal period".

(Overall, `git config -f .gitmodules --get submodule.FastFold.path` is correct and a whole lot simpler.)

Comment: Thank you. Adding the `\.` at the beginning of the regex put me on the right path.